# Restrict external TypeScript function to accept only string literal types

Tags: typescript

Supposing an external library has a function that takes a string, is there a way to restrict that so it **must** be a string matching a literal type?

For example, suppose this method exists in an external interface:
`foo(bar: string): SomeType`

Is there a better way to limit the types of strings that can be provided than the following?:

```
foo(bar: 'foo' | 'bar'): SomeType;
foo(bar: string): never;
```

This *almost* does what I want. If you call `foo('nope')` you don't get an error, but if you try to do anything with the return value, you'll get a type error.

Ideally, it would see that 'nope' is not allowed, and you'd get the error at the function call, rather than when you try to work with it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible since the new type must be the same as the original.

Comment: Would you be willing to write an adapter/wrapper that you call instead of the original library, and use something like ESLint [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports) to require calling your wrapper instead?

Comment: When you say "get an error", do you mean getting a type error or a runtime error? Do you want to write a type definition that allows you to: 1. pass `'foo'` or `'bar'` and get a value, or 2. pass a string and get a type error on the parameter but have a return value? I'm not sure I follow, but `foo(bar: never): SomeType;` does this, but it's arguably very confusing to use.

Comment: Are you using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to add those two signatures as overloads?  If that's what you're doing then you're out of luck, if you succeed in making `foo('nope')` an error on every additional signature, the original signature is still there ready to accept it.  I don't think you can merge your way out of this problem. You'd need to do something else like wrap the original library or locally fork its typings.